# How to calculate the price of a product using a discount in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a products table where I store the original price and a discount percentage:

```
mysql> select * from products;
+---------------+--------+-----------+--------+
| concept       | price  | discount  | currency |
+---------------+--------+-----------+--------+
| yyy           |      1 |      0.00 | usd    |
| xxx           |     10 |     50.00 | usd    |
+---------------+--------+-----------+--------+
```

How could I calculate the total price of each item in a SELECT stament using the price and discount column so I can get the following

```
mysql> select ???????
+---------------+--------+--------+
| concepto      | total  | currency |
+---------------+--------+--------+
| yyy           |     1  | usd    |
| xxx           |     5  | usd    |
+---------------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2):

That's simple arithmetics:

```
select 
    concept,
    price * (1 - discount / 100) total,
    currency
from products
```